# why we can use code $this-> in system/library/customer.php

Tags: opencart2.x

Look at the codes below:

```
public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->config = $registry->get('config');
        $this->db = $registry->get('db');
        $this->request = $registry->get('request');
        $this->session = $registry->get('session');
```

My question is the properties `$this->config`, `$this->db`, $this->request and `$this->session` are not defined at this class. And the Customer class neither inherits from another class not implements `__get(),__set()` method...

Can someone can explain to me why we can use `$this->` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just a variable which will be Declared and assigned value while Object is created,

try

```
class Test{

    function __construct(){
        $this->name = 'Ramesh';
    }
}
print_r(new Test());
```